# Modernizer why there is a space before js class in HTML tag

Tags: modernizr

I know it sounds like a stupid but I need to get it resolved.

```
Why is there a space before js class in HTML tag when using modernizer

<html lang="fr" class=" js ........">
```

I had downloaded it from modernizer directly with out any changes. Even modernizer site doesn't have such issue. Why I am having so. Below is the link to the image.

[images of chrome debugger](http://tinypic.com/r/2n8y4pc/8)

I need to get it resolved. I see the same issue on other sites also. For eg:-
[js class space](https://learnable.com/books/HTMLCSS1/online/apa.html)

I have no idea where is the issue. I don't have much customized JS

There is [main.js](http://pastebin.com/tfSKnzbB) where my custom scripts are loaded. Before that I have jquery.js and modernizer.js with no customization.

I even tried removing space before js class directly in modernizer.js

```
?" js "+v.join(" "):"")

But my clients says the space must be there for a good reason. There is no way     modernizer developer can leave the bug like this. So we are not going to touch it. We should look other issue to fixed this.
```

You see I am in trouble now. :D

[Site](http://www.conseil-general.com/) where the issue is.

Comment: You'll need to share the code or a site in order for people to help., since it isn't happening elsewhere. Also - why do you need to get it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr has a space before the `js` so that it can easily concatenate against existing classNames (which is just a string).

It really has zero impact on anything, so I am not sure why you feel it needs to be resolved.

Regardless, you can just add a random classname, with no whitespace. so what is currently

`<html>`

and becomes

`<html class=" js...">`

can be

`<html class="funkycoldmedina">`

which will be

`<html class="funkycoldmedina js...">`

after modernizr runs.

Comment: Even after adding any classes its same. The space appears to be there. However, I can't see the same space on modernizr official site. When I inspect the js, I can see that space but not in classes ? Why do I have that space?